# What is "capacitive effect" in terms of battery research?

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, batteries, electrical-engineering

For example, the paper I am reading states that the current was "periodically interrupted without changing polarity" to "demonstrate that the peaking behavior is not due to a capacitive effect."

They observe a standard voltage trace. What does "capacitive effect" mean in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batteries act like voltage sources but are not ideal. They also act as if they have a resistor (called *internal resistance*) in series with the voltage source and they can act a little like capacitors as well (being able to store and release charges on short timescales).

That "phantom capacitor" appears between the positive and negative terminals of the nonideal battery. When that battery is suddenly connected to a load, the capacitive effect allows a sudden and brief surge or "transient* of current to flow out of the battery which the electrochemistry of the battery itself couldn't ordinarily provide. This is the sort of thing that "peaking behavior" refers to.

When studying the performance of a battery, its nonidealities must be characterized and this includes any capacitor-like behavior (which, per the above, is part of the "peaking behavior" of the battery when it is presented with a quickly-interrupted load), which must be subtracted out of the data so it does not disguise itself as some meaningful aspect of the battery's behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wonder (if not from the electrochemistry of the battery itself) where is this current coming from?

Comment: @Alexis_Rose it's a capacitive effect similar to what current due to a discharging capacitor does. So the obvious guess is that the current is coming from separated charge sitting at different parts of the cell/battery, similarly as if there was a hidden capacitor inside.

Comment: Very interesting--thank you for giving me a sense of this!